# xcopy doesn't work when in a makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, xcopy

I ran into the error `[copyResources] Error 4` when trying to build a project I downloaded on a 64 bit Windows 7 install. In the Makefile Qt generates, it contains the following two lines:

```
copyResources:
    xcopy "D:\Downloads\GraphViz\GraphViz\res" "D:\Downloads\GraphViz\build-GraphViz-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug" /e /y
```

The make is failing when it hits this target, with the error `Invalid number of parameters`. I originally assumed a malformed command, but if I run it in command prompt, it works fine. Even stranger, if I copy and paste that exact command into `xcopycall.bat` and change the Makefile to the following

```
copyResources:
    xcopycall
```

then everything works fine. Switching to `/` doesn't help, so it doesn't appear to be an escaping issue. Why does running it from a batch file as opposed to in a Makefile fix this?

Comment: Try using "\" instead of single quotes - err, i just took a closer look and there are no spaces, so should actually be fine

Comment: mingw32-make has the nasty habit of running commands through sh instead of cmd if it can find sh.exe in PATH. Make sure that you don't have it added by cygwin or by git (if you chose the complete unix utility folder to be added to PATH during installation).

Comment: @jturcotte's comment is the answer. Just add one point that I got from the #qt IRC. Use "where sh" inside CMD on windows to find the location of the sh.exe

Answer (score 0):

What jturcotte and lixiang said is right, in my case, `sh.exe` is in the dir `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, but removing the dir from `Path` is undesired, so I commented lines about `xcopy` in the "GraphViz.pro". It's not elegant, but works :P